# iOS data over data headphone port

Tags: ios

Hardware accessories like the Square Card Reader use the audio (headphone) port to transfer data.

What API in the iOS SDK accomplish this?

Comment: You can generate waveforms using the CoreAudio framework.

Comment: I think the issue is more for decoding the waveform and not generating the data.  What you receive over the audio port will be FSK data.  I would guess that you can implement a software modem on the iOS side but I am wondering if there is "canned" way of doing this.

Comment: So also found this - http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/sensor-data-to-iphone-through-the-headphone-jack-using-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

If you look on your official Apple headphones, there's 3 rings around the connector tip. Usually headphones only have two (I assume, one for left channel, other for right channel). The 3rd ring is meant for the waveforms being sent from the volume controls on the headphones.

If you custom built your own hardware, you can send waveforms over that 3rd ring tip using Core Audio and have your app respond to any controls on the hardware.

Comment: Isn't the third ring for the microphone?

Comment: Yeah, the controls are using the same microphone port. I'm pretty sure if you use a voice recorder while the headphone is plugged in and start pressing on the volume controls, you'll hear some high pitched patterns in the recording.
Essentially, you're using the microphone port to send waveforms over for decoding.